# Code doesn't work and I don't know why. Making Hangman game

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm new to C++ and coding. I tried to make a hangman game as a beginner project. The problem I have is that the game only works when the letters of the word is typed in order. If the word is "flow" for instance, I have to type each letter consecutively (f,l,o,w). Any other variations is not accepted and I don't know why. I need help debugging this issue. I'm not sure if `.replace` is the method I should be using here. I found this method on the internet and I thought it would do what I needed it to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string getString(char guess) {
  string s(1, guess);
  return s;
}

int main() {
  unsigned int seed;
  int randomNumber = 0;
  char guess;
  string underscore;
  seed = time(0);

  cout << "Hangman game\n";

  srand(seed);
  randomNumber = (rand() % 5);

  string wordList[5] = {"closet", "flow", "sheep", "see", "chocolate"};
  string word = wordList[randomNumber];
  int wordLength = word.length();

  cout << "The word has " << wordLength << " letters\n";

  for (int x = 0; x < wordLength; x++) {
    underscore += "_ ";
  }
  cout << underscore << endl;

  string holder = underscore;
  for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
    cout << "\n\nType in a letter: ";
    cin >> guess;

    if (guess == word[j]) {
      size_t found = word.find(guess);

      holder.replace(found, 2, getString(guess));
      cout << "\n";
      word.replace(found, 1, "*");

      cout << holder;
    }
    else {
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that you mix two things, the number of tries and the length of the word. For the first aspect, simplest method seems to use a `while(true)` loop and to ` break` when the word is found. If inside this loop we use a `for` loop for examing each character, you don't need to use a `find` or `replace` method. However, using them may avoid the `for` loop.

Comment: "Finding it on the internet" is not a good reason to use something. You need to apply some scientific, analytical reasoning to why you write a particular line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some observations that might help you:

1. Don’t declare all variables at the top of your function. Declare them **as you need them**.
2. **Avoid hard-coding** (`wordList[5]`). Add as many as strings as you need in your array. Use the following to find out how many are (see [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)):

   ```
   string wordList[] = { "closet", "flow", "sheep", "see", "chocolate" };
   size_t wordCount = sizeof wordList / sizeof wordList[0];
   ```
3. You do **not need to manually fill** the `underscore` string. Use the following constructor:

   ```
   string underscore(word.length(), '_');
   ```
4. The user might enter **uppercase letters**. Convert them to lowercase. Otherwise you will not find them:

   ```
   guess = tolower(guess);
   ```
5. You do not need fancy functions to find out where the entered character is located. **Just use a loop**:

   ```
   //...

   bool found = true;
   for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
   {
     if (word[i] == guess) // is the letter at position i the same as the one entered?
       underscore[i] = guess; // replace it
     if (underscore[i] == '_')
       found = false;
   }

   if (found)
   {
     cout << "Good job!" << endl;
     return 0;
   }

   //...
   ```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. The game works now I just wanted to have a space between the underscores and have it removed somehow when you guess a right letter so it looks cleaner but that was too hard for me to make hence the problems in my code  I think. Thanks again

Comment: @Beza It's a good idea to store information in a very simple format that's easy to test and manipulate. You can make it look pretty when you display it if you want. But it's generally not a good idea to store the data in a display format because it makes manipulating it much harder and more error-prone. (It also makes it *much* harder to change the display format or experiment with different ways to present information to the user.)